# How to make a sass based grid system with small through large columns

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, zurb-foundation

I can't seem to find what I'm looking for on Google. I am trying to set up a responsive grid system that uses columns like foundation or bootstrap. Basically I want to pull off `column column-med column-lg` but I don't understand how column-med is supposed to override column-lg when it changes breakpoints. I know it has to be a breakpoint somehow, but I want use a sass map to do this and not have a ton of media queries. Could someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a mixin for the media queries. Something like:

```
@mixin small {
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        @content;
    }
}
@mixin medium {
    @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Do the same for any sizes you want. In order to call that mixin in your .scss file you would do the following.

```
@include small {
  //Your css rules here
}

@include small {
  //Your css rules here
}
```

To make a grid you want to use flexbox to make your columns. First start with you default columns.

```
.col {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box; //so that the padding is included in the size
}

.col-6 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

So that will make two columns for any size window with the class 'col' and 'col-6'. Also, you don't have to use the 'col' class if you don't want gutters.

Then make classes with media queries.

```
@include small {
  .col-sm-6 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

@include medium {
  .col-md-4 {
    flex-basis: 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
  }
}
```

That's it. Just add the classes 'col' and 'col-sm-6' and 'col-md-4' you'll have one column from 0-767 pixels wide, two from 768 to 1023 and three from 1024+.

Comment: The numbers 6 and 4 come from a 12 column grid. Also, [https://github.com/alistairtweedie/Pintsize/] is a great resource for this.

Comment: Mitchell, the link you've provided does not work.

Comment: It looks like my link has since been broken. Sorry for the inconvenience